# Use a different drawable for menu item based on sdk level?

Tags: android

I'd like a menu item to use a different drawable depending on api level:

```
// my_menu.xml
<menu>
  <item android:icon="@style/foo"/>
</menu>

// values/styles.xml
<drawable name="foo">@drawable/apple</drawable>

// values-v11/styles.xml
<drawable name="foo">@drawable/orange</drawable>
```

Doesn't seem to work though - is there a way to do that?

Thank you

------------- Update ------------------

Ok after some more reading, this is how I did it:

```
// my_menu.xml
<menu>
  <item style="@style/foo"/>
</menu>

// values/styles.xml
<style name="foo">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/apple</item>
</style>

// values-v11/styles.xml
<style name="foo">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/orange</item>
</style>
```

I think this is what lxx is suggesting.

Comment: Why you don't use item tag instead of drawable?

Comment: Hi, sorry can you please elaborate, I don't follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this programatically after you inflate your menu in your code.

```
        onCreateWhateverMenu(Menu menu){

        ///inflate menu
        ...

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(itemId)
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == <insert API level>){
           item.setIcon(your Drawable);
        }
        else{
           item.setIcon(other Drawable);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I can do it that way for sure, was hoping for a pure xml way to keep this detail out of the code. Thank you!